# Django annotation across multiple models

Tags: django, django-orm

I am looking to annotate to each BonusCustomer the Sum of `billable_amount` from the load table.

```
class BonusCustomer(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    dispatcher = models.ForeignKey(Dispatcher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    pick_city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

class Load(models.Model):
    load_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    sales_agent = models.ForeignKey(Dispatcher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, to_field='name', blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=320, null=True, blank=True)
    total_miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    billable_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class Dispatcher(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I tried
`bonus_customers=BonusCustomer.objects.annotate(revenue=Sum('dispatcher__load__billable_amount'))` but this gives me the total load revenue for each dispatcher, not BonusCustomer. Any help is appreciated.

I'm thinking it should be possible with a Subquery, but am not sure how to reference the BonusCustomer:

```
bonus_customers = BonusCustomer.objects.annotate(
revenue = Subquery(Load.objects.filter(customer='here I want to reference the current BonusCustomer object')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
loads = Load.objects.filter(customer=OuterRef('customer'))\
    .values('customer').annotate(revenue=Sum('billable_amount'))

bonus_customers = BonusCustomer.objects.annotate(
    revenue=Subquery(loads.values('revenue')
)
```

By the way, why not use a foreign key towards BonusCustomer under Load?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm!
To your question why I did not set the customer field under Load as Foreign key to BonusCustomer: because not all customers are BonusCustomers. I am not sure if this is right or not. But a BonusCustomer is a customer, but not every customer is a BonusCustomer.